# Need To Use Dynamic Custom Connection Class for connection pooling in java

Tags: java, connection, database-connection, connection-pooling, tomcat-dbcp

I am thinking of implementing connection pool for DB Connections using dbcp2.

But I am using different types of custom connection classes.

How can I override the Datasource class to use dynamic custom connection classes(Say MyConnectionClass1, MyConnectionClass2, etc..) based on the input?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you you mean by **input**?
It's possible you are needed same **DatasourceFactory**?

```
public DatasourceFactory {
   public Datasource instance(Object sameParameter) {
      if(// condition one for sameParameter) {
         return new MyConnectionClass1DataSource();
      } else {
         return new MyConnectionClass2DataSource();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Input means that it specifies if ssl required or type of database. And The databases are not the same for every request.

Comment: Can You give more details on this answer. How can a connection class be returned as DataSourceFactory?

Comment: Sorry. I made mistake. Signature of method must be (return Datasource not DataSourceFactory):
`public Datasource instance(Object sameParameter) {
   ...   
}`

DatasourceFactory returns Datasource and Datasource.getConnection() returns connection.

Comment: No Issues, I just need to change the connection class **"Connection"** to **"MyConnectionClass"** for the BasicDataSource. Need knowledge on that!!

Comment: When I call dataSource.getConnection() I should get MyConnectionClass as return type instead of Connection.

Comment: Ok. But you can specify several Datasources for different databases?

Comment: Datasources may be Mysql, Postgres, Mongodb etc..
For handling that I have planned to create multiple ConnectionPools.

The only issue is using my own Connection class inside the connection pool